# Can reduce the 994 GB partition on Dell Vostro 3580 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, dell

I am somewhat newcomer to computers and want to help me.
I bought a Dell Vostro 3580 laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 pre-installed.

I could reduce the 994 GB partition to about  450 GB.
In the free space could I install Ubuntu Studio 19.10?
If yes, how can i do it?

[specs](https://www.pcgarage.ro/notebook-laptop/dell/156-vostro-3580-seria-3000-fhd-procesor-intel-core-i7-8565u-8m-cache-up-to-460-ghz-8gb-ddr4-256gb-ssd-radeon-520-2gb-linux-black-3yr/) and [docs](https://www.dell.com/support/home/ro/ro/robsdt1/product-support/product/vostro-15-3580-laptop/docs)

[image: screenshot of GParted]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: Be sure to install in same boot mode. It should be UEFI, so boot live installer in UEFI boot mode. If planning on using both systems, often better to have smaller / (root) partitions of 25GB and large separate shared data partition with data you can access from both systems. Best not to share /home. If you have swap partition that can be shared if not encrypted install. New installs now use swap file, so you may not have swap partition.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: So far we have not used / installed systems in UEFI mode.
Can I use GNOME Disks instead of Gparted for partition resizing?          https://ibb.co/58X7S0g                                                                             Ubuntu 18.04 came with GNOME Disks installed.

Comment: Yes, you can use GNOME-Disks and I have amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: @oldfred, I like your idea, but Snaps take up so much more room nowadays that I don't think 25GB is adequate for a system partition with /home included.

Comment: I apologize for the delay.
I tried to see with GNOME Disks how to reduce the 994 GB partition.
An authentication request for disassembly appeared to me.
Common fact when I installed two other systems (ubuntu and debian) on the same hard drive.
I'm interested to find out what may happen to me when I resize Ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled and install the second Ubuntu system.
Do I need to prepare Ubuntu Studio for UEFI?
Thank you all for your help.

Comment: An issue that will help me a lot (help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI – oldfred).  Thank you                                                                                                                geo

Comment: Eliah Kagan Thank you.                                                                                       geo

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have two different versions of Ubuntu, you can do so by following the standard installation process with two amendments.

First, before you start installation, boot with a LiveUSB with Ubuntu Studio on it.

Launch [gparted](https://gparted.org) or [GNOME-disks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disks.1.html) and check to see *if* you have a swap partition (*typically only if you use Hibernation with 16.04 and later, or before 16.04*); if you do, open a terminal and do `swapoff -a` to temporarily dismount it. If you do not have a swap partition, no problem, carry on.

With [gparted](https://gparted.org) or [GNOME-disks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disks.1.html), resize your 18.04 system partition (typically ext4, FYI, **think three times** before changing anything about a FAT32 partition,especially /boot/efi !) to the size you wish, and then exit from [gparted](https://gparted.org) or [GNOME-disks](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/gnome-disks.1.html).

oldfred wisely suggested

> If planning on using both systems, often better to have smaller /
>   (root) partitions of 25GB and large separate shared data partition
>   with data you can access from both systems. Best not to share /home.
>   If you have swap partition that can be shared if not encrypted
>   install.

If you like that option (and it is just an option), I would make larger system partitions, since nowadays apps installed as Snaps consume significantly more space than before. Maybe 50GB per system partition?

Perform installation following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0 until you reach **6. Allocate drive space** where you will instead choose Something Else, and install Studio into the unallocated space.

Comment: Without seeing a `gparted` screenshot, you can't be sure with these instructions. There may be other existing partitions that might also require moving before trying to install Studio. And... I'd suggest a different term than "boot partition".

Comment: sorry for the delay.
I did not really manage to post the image.
geo                                   https://ibb.co/nz8Q4ZR